# NoMethodError (filtered_parameters)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed Rails 3.0.10 on my server and keep getting this message on my newly created controller:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `filtered_parameters' for nil:NilClass):
```

Any suggestion on how to resolve this? Cant seem to find the cause...

Comment: Please show us your application.rb (config dir)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess I solved my own problem... You can't have a method in a controller called 'request'... *sighs*

Comment: Glad I found this answer! Saved me probably hours of pain :P